# How to find the specific line on a big data that is causing error in python script?

Tags: python, data-structures, error-handling

I was able to write a program in python to do my data analyses. The program runs all well with a small **mcve data** from beginning to end. But, when I run it using my big dataset all works well until somewhere the data structure gets faulty and I get `TypeError`. Since the program is big and creates several data on the fly, I am not able to track at which specific line of the big data is the data-structure really messed up.

Problem: I want to know at what line of my data is the data structure wrong. Any easy way to do it.

I can tell from which function the problem is coming from. But, my problem isn't with the function, but the data structure which probably has a subtle structural problem somewhere. The data runs through several times until it hits the problem, but I cannot tell where. I tried adding a print function to visually trace it down. But, the data is so huge and lots of similar patterns and is really hard trace it back to the main-big  data.

I am not sure if I should put my scripts here, but I think there are possible suggestions I can receive without writing my program on SE.

Any info appreciated.

Comment: Do you check out traceback of your code?

Comment: Yes, I do. I can tell from which function the problem is coming from. But, my problem isn't with the function, but the data structure which probably has a subtle structural problem somewhere. The data runs through several times until it hits the problem, but I cannot tell where. I tried adding a print function visually trace it down. But, the data is so huge and lots of similar patterns and is really hard to find visually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code would help, but without it, all I can think of is to keep track of the line number and include it with your error. Use a try.

```
line_number = 0
for line in your_file: 
   line_number += 1
   try:
     <do your thing>
   except(TypeError):
     print("Error at line number {}".format(line_number))
```

EDIT: This will simply print the line number and keep going. You could also raise the error if you want to halt processing.

Comment: Good first answer!

Comment: Thanks! :) Hope it helps.